# Integrate the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Is $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$. Justify the equality: $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$.

Comment: Interchange summation and integration

Comment: @Alex This requires justification, though.

Answer (score 1):

As
$$\left|\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)\right|\le\frac{|x|}{n^2}\le\frac1{n^2},$$
you can apply the $M$-thest to the series.

Comment: Beat me by 1 second.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre, :-)

Comment: this does not justify equality, only proves that the series converges uniformly

Comment: @JoseLucianoTerhorst, and the primitive of $\sin(x/n^2)$ is...

Answer (score 0):

Put $f_n(x) = \sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$,and observe that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{0}^1 |f_n(x)|dx \leq \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{x}{n^2}dx = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12} < \infty$. So by Fubini's theorem, you can interchange the integral and the sum,and thus arrive at the desire answer.